# How to solve the issue passing an unknown-sized 2D array to a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, multidimensional-array

I have a program in which the object array's size is determined during the runtime, so it's dynamically allocated (2D array, read from file). I also have a function which takes these objects as parameters. The problem is if the function parameters are 2D arrays that are passed to the function the 2nd dimension should be determined. However, in my case it is not. My program won't compile since the prototype does not have the 2nd dimension mentioned.

Here is what I tried:

```
//global variables
int residentCount=0;
int hospitalCount=0;
Resident** residents;
Hospital** hospitals;
bool readFromFiles(const string, const string, const int); //sizes are determined in here
void print(Hospital*[hospitalCount], Resident*[residentCount]); //declaration issue
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Stop using pointers when you need dynamic arrays, and start using `std::vector`.

Comment: and why exactly should i do that?

Comment: Because then you don't have to worry about these things. Using [the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) _will_ make your life easier as a C++ programmer.

Comment: I see the difficulties now:) next time, definitely, i'll use it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Please post a solution so that we can upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***You are programming in C++, so you should:***

- avoid dynamic allocation and handling memory management on your own always when it's possible

  - take advantage of objects with automatic storage duration instead, follow [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)
- avoid using C-style arrays and actually avoid writing C code that is just compilable as C++ in general

  - use great features that C++ provides, especially those bundled within STL
- avoid using global variables when local equivalents suffice

This is how it could look like:

```
typedef std::vector<Resident> Residents;
typedef std::vector<Hospital> Hospitals;

// passing by const reference:
void print(const std::vector<Hospitals>&, const std::vector<Residents>&);

int main()
{
    std::vector<Hospitals> hospitals;
    std::vector<Residents> residents;
    ...
} // <-- lifetime of automatics declared within main ends here
```

Note that `hospitals` and `residents` will be objects with automatic storage duration, usable in similar manner than your C-style 2D arrays. When the execution goes out of the scope of `main`, these vectors are destructed and memory, where their elements (including elements of their elements) resided before is automatically cleaned up.

Also note that I suggest you to pass by const reference, i.e. `const std::vector<Hospitals>&`, which prevents the copy of passed object being created and `const` keyword explicitely tells to the caller: *"Although you pass this object by reference, I will not change it."*

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. This particular program taught me what you said (experience is everything, right?). Now I understand the beauty of the STL containers:)

Answer (score 3):

Just pass a pointer to the first element of the array and the dimensions, that's enough, example:

```
void PrintHospitals(Hospital* Hospitals, size_t HospitalRows, size_t HospitalColumns)
{
  size_t i, j;
  Hospital* hospital;

  for (i = 0; i < HospitalRows; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < HospitalColumns; j++)
    {
      hospital = Hospitals + HospitalColumns * i + j;
      PrintHospital(hospital);
    }
}

int main()
{
  Hospital hospitals[10][20];
  // ...
  PrintHospitals(&hospitals[0][0], 10, 20);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a solution, I understand your answer well, but I don't find it semantically convenient. Do you think it is semantically convenient? I mean, what I wan't is to pass my whole array to the function whose dimensions are determined during runtime, and print it. I don't really want to play with the code, doing something works but instead I'm also looking for a 'right' way. I'll try this workaround if there really is no other way (I don't accept changing the data structure as an other way).

Comment: Nobody's preventing you from allocating the array dynamically (via new or malloc or whatever) and passing variables instead of hard-coded dimensions like 10 and 20 in the example. Can you see what I'm talking about?

Comment: Yes, i do. Im not talking about that, im talking about you re-dimensioning the array and making it a 1D array and arrange the loops so that as it was a 2D array. That was what I have been referring as "semantically inconvenient", not the static sizes of the array.

Comment: I'm sorry, but "semantically inconvenient" doesn't make any sense to me. It's valid code and it solves your problem. If you don't like it for whatever aesthetic or other reasons you may have, don't use it.

Comment: I don't know why you have taken offense, my intention was definitely not that and I'm grateful for your answer in the first place. Just wanted to let you know that..

Comment: There's no offense. The phrase "semantically inconvenient" really doesn't ring any bell to me. :) And choice is in SO's nature, you can choose or up-vote whatever answer you like. There isn't always one right way to do everything, you can choose what's righter (sic) for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using templates to create two-dimensional array wrappers for existing data:

```
template<typename T>
class Array2d {
  public:
  int Rows;
  int Cols;
  T** Data;

  Array2d(int rows, int cols, T** data) :
    Rows(rows),
    Cols(cols),
    Data(data) { }
};

void print(Array2d<Hospital> h, Array2d<Resident> r) {
  for (int i = 0; i < h.Rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < h.Cols; j++) {
      //Print Data[i][j] element here
    }
  }
  // Other print code
}

int main()
{
   Resident** residents;
   Hospital** hospitals;

   //Init data arrays

   Array2d<Hospital> h(10, 10, hospitals);
   Array2d<Resident> r(10, 10, residents);

   print(h, r);
}
```